# Can browserify display a backtrace to dianose require() calls?

Tags: javascript, build, browserify

I have several dependencies between my JavaScript files. When running `browserify` over them, the error message doesn't say which file could not pull in a dependency.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mapping' from '...'
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:17
    at process (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:173:43)
    at ondir (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:188:17)
    at load (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
    at onex (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
```

Is there any way to make `browserify` say *"I can't find the 'mapping' dependency from within 'whatever.js'"?*

Comment: It does tell you which file: whichever one exports the module `mapping`. This is almost certainly a file that you wrote, since any of your dependencies would have failed to install properly if they had this issue.

Comment: The `...` in the question is a directory. E.g., "Cannot find module 'mapping' from 'src/inf/wizard'". It doesn't tell me which file in the `wizard` directory is to blame.

Comment: `grep -lr --exclude-dir=".git;.svn" "mapping" .` in the root of your app. Also, considering it's your app one might assume you would be familiar with which file exports the module `mapping`, not least because in an ideal app structure each module is exported in its own file, so you should be looking for the file `Mapping.js`